# What is the optimal time for a user on Login Page?

Tags: login, ux-field, users, signup-signon

Google Analytics shows that my users need 30 seconds on average to complete the login, while a lot of password resets happen.

What is the optimal timeframe a user should spent on the login page?

Is there any documentation or books to read on this matter?

Comment: The less the better, as long as it's secure.

Comment: Do you have any other information that might tell us more about the type of application that the user is interacting with, and why it would take this amount of time to complete the login? Most of the answers really depend on the context of usage and the type of users you are dealing with, so rather than a hard and fast rule, perhaps more details would help in getting more detailed answers to your question :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**The answer is: as fast as possible**

Logging in is no user goal. It's simply a security gate that actually hinders the user in achieving his goal.

A login page should be as clear as possible. Don't display anything that isn't needed.

Provide a clear form that is easy to read and easy to understand.

[**This article sums up pretty good how you can improve your forms**.](https://uxplanet.org/the-18-must-do-principles-in-the-form-design-fe89d0127c92)

30 Seconds for a login is way too much, assuming you only need one identification characteristic (e-mail, username, ID) and password.

**What you can do to limit password resets:**

- Provide the option to make the password visible as cleartext
- Give the user a hint if Caps Lock is activated
- Give users the option to set password-hints (like Windows and Apple do for example)

If you would provide an image of your current login page it would be easier to find out what reasons might make it hard for users to log in.

Comment: Also add option "keep me logged in", add login via google or facebook, make sure browser autosave is enabled / possible....

Comment: Hiya. Great feedback. Thank you for answering so fast.. I kinda suspected it was way too long but just wanted to confirm with another professional such as you. Regards Estela

Comment: +1, might also help to re-evaluate password requirements. Could be that the requirements are forcing people to make passwords they won't remember, because they have to use a mandatory symbol, can't use two same letters in row, capital, or similar.